# How to stop /dev/random population from entropy pool. Can I unload a module to do it?

Tags: linux, kernel-module, entropy

I'm making a TRNG that talks to my PC via USB as a CDC device. I want to stop /dev/random from sourcing entropy from the entropy pool entirely and use my data instead. The theory is that the pool can be poisoned because of the way it currently collects entropy.

I know how to remove sources of entropy, but that requires hacking about in the kernel. It is an option but I would prefer to just unload the module that writes data to /dev/random. I've tried rmmod and modprobe stuff but can't figure out the name of the module. It is possible I'm just leaving out an extension or something but I'm new to the whole business of messing about with kernel modules so I can't really tell.

Also

```
modprobe -l | grep random
```

just gives me a list of hw_random stuff and

```
lsmod | grep random
```

gives me nothing.

So I'm not sure if I'm really on the right track.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There seems to be no module that provides `/dev/random` and `dev/urandom`, the functionality is probably built into the kernel proper. These devices are registered and the major and minor numbers are assigned for them by `chr_dev_init()` in [drivers/char/mem.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/mem.c). See also the definition of `devlist` there. The operations (`random_fops`) are defined in [drivers/char/random.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c). Take a look also at the Makefile `drivers/char/` directory...

Comment: (...continued) There is the following line in this Makefile: `obj-y += mem.o random.o`. That is, the code from `mem.c` and `random.c` is probably always built into the kernel itself. So, there is no module that could be unloaded to disable this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the /dev/random node and made a new one with a different major minor number pair. The standard module still hangs out but it doesn't touch the new node.